# Estimating conditional entropy of a series

Tags: python, probability, entropy

I have a time series $Y$ (continuous values) and I want to estimate its conditional entropy such that $H(y_{t+1}|y_t)$ represents the conditional entropy of $Y$ at time $t+1$ given its value at time $t$:

$$ H(y_{t+1}|y_t) = - \sum_{y_{t+1},y_t} p(y_t+1,y_t) \log \frac{p(y_{t+1},y_t)}{p(y_t)} $$

Could someone tell how I could implement this in Python? Should I use KDE?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: Might be [scipy.stats.entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) in conjunction with `pandas.Series.shift()`?

Comment: What is your probability model?